# Работа с LIMIT в запросе с UNION MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Имею такой запрос MySQL. Подскажите куда мне воткнуть оператор LIMIT для того чтобы этот запрос выдавал 10 последних строк таблицы. Всё осложняется наличием UNION.

```
SELECT 
    from_login
  , from_open_key
  , encrypt_by_from_key
  , who_login
  , who_open_key
  , encrypt_by_who_key
  , date_time 
FROM Messages 
WHERE 
    from_login = '".$_POST['login']."' 
    AND who_login='".$_POST["who"]."' 
UNION 
SELECT 
    from_login
  , from_open_key
  , encrypt_by_from_key
  , who_login, who_open_key
  , encrypt_by_who_key
  , date_time 
FROM Messages 
WHERE  
    from_login = '".$_POST['who']."' 
    AND who_login='".$_POST["login"]."'  
ORDER BY date_time asc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конструкция `LIMIT` размещается после `ORDER BY`. В данном случае `LIMIT` действует на всю выборку - будет возвращено только 10 записей

```
SELECT
  from_login,
  from_open_key,
  encrypt_by_from_key,
  who_login,
  who_open_key,
  encrypt_by_who_key,
  date_time
FROM
  Messages
WHERE
  from_login = '".$_POST['login']."' AND who_login='".$_POST["who"]."'
UNION
SELECT
  from_login,
  from_open_key,
  encrypt_by_from_key,
  who_login,
  who_open_key,
  encrypt_by_who_key,
  date_time
FROM
  Messages
WHERE
  from_login = '".$_POST['who']."' AND who_login='".$_POST["login"]."'
ORDER BY
  date_time DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Для того, чтобы отсортировать записи в обратном хронологическом порядке следует заменить в конструкции `ORDER BY` ключевое слово `ASC` на `DESC`.